# "Not Authorized" warnings with Slim desktop Manager on Debian

Tags: debian, power-management, xorg

Recently I changed my desktop manager to use slim desktop manager and .xsessionrc to launch appropriate session. I’m attaching my .xsessionrc and slim.conf with this
Now after using X directly without gdm or kdm my laptop doesn’t suspend / hibernate on closing laptop lid instead I get “power manager not authorized” also when I try ejecting or mounting usb drive by clicking on thunar filemanager icons I again get “not authorized” error. I'm running Debian Wheezy

I’m not sure what is going wrong can any one point me in right direction

Here is my .xsessionrc file content

```
    synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=1 VertEdgeScroll=1 HorizEdgeScroll=1 CornerCoasting=1
DEFAULT_SESSION=startxfce4

case $1 in
kde)
        exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch startkde
    ;;
xfce4)
        exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch startxfce4
    ;;
dwm)
        exec /usr/bin/dwm-launch
    ;;
wmii)
        feh --bg-scale /home/vasudev/Documents/personal_hacks/wallpapers/UNIX4.png
        volumeicon &
        xfce4-power-manager &
        xscreensaver -no-splash &
        wicd-gtk &
        exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch wmii

    ;;
awesome)
        volumeicon &
        xfce4-power-manager &
        xscreensaver -no-splash &
        wicd-gtk &
        xfce4-notes &
        exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch awesome
    ;;
blackbox)
    exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch blackbox
    ;;
stumpwm)
    xfce4-power-manager&
    exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch stumpwm
*)
    exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch $DEFAULT_SESSION
    ;;
esac
```

and here is the content of /etc/slim.conf

```
# Path, X server and arguments (if needed)
# Note: -xauth $authfile is automatically appended
default_path        /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
default_xserver     /usr/bin/X11/X
xserver_arguments   -nolisten tcp

# Commands for halt, login, etc.
halt_cmd            /sbin/shutdown -h now
reboot_cmd          /sbin/shutdown -r now
console_cmd         /usr/bin/xterm -C -fg white -bg black +sb -T "Console login" -e /bin/sh -c "/bin/cat /etc/issue.net; exec /bin/login"
#suspend_cmd        /usr/sbin/suspend

# Full path to the xauth binary
xauth_path         /usr/bin/X11/xauth

# Xauth file for server
authfile           /var/run/slim.auth


# Activate numlock when slim starts. Valid values: on|off
# numlock             on

# Hide the mouse cursor (note: does not work with some WMs).
# Valid values: true|false
# hidecursor          false

# This command is executed after a succesful login.
# you can place the %session and %theme variables
# to handle launching of specific commands in .xinitrc
# depending of chosen session and slim theme
#
# NOTE: if your system does not have bash you need
# to adjust the command according to your preferred shell,
# i.e. for freebsd use:
# login_cmd           exec /bin/sh - ~/.xinitrc %session
login_cmd           exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch /bin/bash -login /etc/X11/Xsession %session

# Commands executed when starting and exiting a session.
# They can be used for registering a X11 session with
# sessreg. You can use the %user variable
#
# sessionstart_cmd  some command
# sessionstop_cmd   some command

# Start in daemon mode. Valid values: yes | no
# Note that this can be overriden by the command line
# options "-d" and "-nodaemon"
# daemon    yes

# Available sessions (first one is the default).
# The current chosen session name is replaced in the login_cmd
# above, so your login command can handle different sessions.
# see the xinitrc.sample file shipped with slim sources
sessions            default,xfce4,awesome,dwm,wmii,scrotwm,stumpwm

# Executed when pressing F11 (requires imagemagick)
screenshot_cmd      scrot /root/slim.png

# welcome message. Available variables: %host, %domain
welcome_msg         Welcome to %host

# Session message. Prepended to the session name when pressing F1
# session_msg         Session: 

# shutdown / reboot messages
shutdown_msg       The system is halting...
reboot_msg         The system is rebooting...

# default user, leave blank or remove this line
# for avoid pre-loading the username.
#default_user        simone

# Focus the password field on start when default_user is set
# Set to "yes" to enable this feature
#focus_password      no

# Automatically login the default user (without entering
# the password. Set to "yes" to enable this feature
#auto_login          no


# current theme, use comma separated list to specify a set to 
# randomly choose from
current_theme       debian-spacefun

# Lock file
lockfile            /var/run/slim.lock

# Log file
logfile             /var/log/slim.log
```

Answer (score 1):

change `exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch startxfce4`

to `exec dbus-launch startxfce4`

see note in this document https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SLiM#Single_environments

Comment: Ah thanks @k2s I didn't knew that Slim became console-kit capable with version 1.3.3 I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that your login manager does as root to help set up your environment so you can conveniently suspend and access external drives. You should check all of the GDM configuration files to see what you might be able to add to your xsessionrc. Unfortunately, some of it needs to be run before your session is started.

Comment: Normally the powermanager and usb mounting have different users in Arch Linux and having my user under these group solves this issue. But in Debian I don't find such special users!